# data migation vs schema migration (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question is related to SQL server migration.

I know BCP is used for data migration whereas tools such as DAC's (Data tier applications) are used for schema migration.

Generate SCRIPT wizard can do both right?

can BCP perform schema migration? can DAC perform data migration?

it would be great can briefly state the difference between data migration vs schema migration. I read and searched about material that could delineate the difference, but was not able to find it in concise and clear form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer while reading http://www.solidq.com/sqj/Pages/2011-May-Issue/Migrating-Data-into-Microsofts-Data-Platform-SQL-Azure.aspx

Comment: Just to summarize for others: 1. Generate script wizard is not an ideal tool to carry out data migration. 2 DAC v2.0 allows us to create .bacpac's that can carry out schema + data migration

Comment: I have summarized my research here: http://parasdoshi.com/2011/08/15/summary-sql-server-to-sql-azure-migration-paras-doshi/

Answer (score 1):

Paras,

I am NOT sure what you are referring to regarding DAC here. If you mean Dedicated Admin Connection that is NOT helpful in this situation.

You have Database Publishing wizard in SQL Server 2005 and it is integrated in SQL Server 2008 in the SSMS. That will help here but you need to add more details like how many tables, how much data, what's the source & destination. You could also use SSIS here and get minimal logging reducing the overhead.

If you haven't looked at this already, checkout this brief article on different options.
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/title-12

Comment: DAC is data tier applications. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381683%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: There are few confusing TLA (Three Letter Acronyms) from MSFT SQL Server on DAC

Comment: what i am looking for is the comparison hollistically. i found bcp vs SSIS then DAC vs Generate script, etc but i was not able to find article/blog that holistically compared each technique. Also differentiate schema migration vs Data migration. Thanks.